# initializer list for a heap-allocated struct

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project where I would like to heap allocate a struct and initialize it using an initializer list.

```
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo( int a );
};

struct Bar {
    Foo foo;
    int b;
};

Bar a = Bar { Foo( 1 ), 2 };      // Works!
Bar* b = new Bar{ Foo( 1 ), 2 };  // Errors!
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not add a constructor to `Bar` accepting the needed values?

Comment: @Joachim - I probably will end up doing that, but I wanted to verify that it was necessary first. I hate when I end up doing more work because I missed some simple language feature.

Comment: Put on a constructor in your struct.

Comment: Even the latest version of Visual Studio, VS11 beta, does not implement C++11 initializer lists. `Bar a = Bar { Foo( 1 ), 2 };` does not work in VS. gcc does implement these features but gcc 4.5 has a bug that breaks `new Bar{ Foo( 1 ), 2 }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 allows it, or something very similar.  Since you're using VC 2008,
however, this won't help you.  The only solution I know is to create a
local instance with the initialization, and then pass this:

```
Bar forInitialization = { Foo( 1 ), 2 };
Bar* b = new Bar( forInitialization );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Bar* b = new Bar({ Foo( 1 ), 2 });
```

Disclamer: only tested with GCC `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constructor to your struct, it will be called when `new` is invoked